# Passing all params through an event prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a `<Link />` component that’s essentially just a styled `<a />` tag. It takes an `href` prop as well as an optional `onClick`. If an `onClick` is passed in, I want to `preventDefault()` the event and call the `onClick` prop.

Currently my component looks something like this:

```js
<a
    aria-label={ ariaLabel }
    className={ className }
    href={ href }
    onClick={ handleOnClick }
    target={ target }
    { ...rest }
>
    {children}
</a>
```

Then I have the following function:

```js
const handleOnClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    onClick(event);
};
```

This works fine unless there are params passed in with the `onClick`. My `handleOnClick` function just passes the event back and the params are lost. How can I pass any and all params back that might have been passed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going a different direction altogether. The issue was that the app that consumes my component library required certain parameters to be returned from my components with events like `onClick`. Parameters like `vendorId` and `action`. So, instead of creating `vendorId` and `action` props in my component, which don’t really make sense when you’re working on a generic component that shouldn’t care what `vendorId` is, I created an `eventData` prop that allows the consumer to set whatever data they want in an object, and that object will be passed back to `onClick`.

The component I’m currently working on is a menu, so I set added an `eventData` prop to my `menuItems`:

```js
menuItems: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
        badge: PropTypes.number,
        eventData: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
        group: PropTypes.string,
        icon: PropTypes.oneOf([...ICONS, 'coin']),
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
),
```

Then each menu button has this `onClick`:

```
<SimpleMenuButton onClick={ event => handleOnClick(event, item.eventData) }>
```

… then the `handleOnClick` handler:

```js
const handleOnClick = (event, data) => {
    onClick(event, data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
const handleOnClick = (event, ...args) => {
    // here args will be an array.
    // so loop through it for additional arguments
    event.preventDefault();
    onClick(event);
};
```